# How to insert dynamic data and static input data to mysql using ajax, dynamic data will not insert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a modal form with static input fields and dynamic input fields.

currently the data is being sent to the mysql database, the static fields are being inserted into the database but the dynamic fields are not being inserted.

The form data has to inserted into three mysql tables. tables are orders, products and sma.

**HTML input code**

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="insertModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
    <form class="well form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Insert Order Details</h3>
                </div><hr>
        <fieldset>

            <!-- Text input-->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="customer" class="col-md-4 control-label">Customer Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input name="customer" id="customer" placeholder="Customer" class="form-control" type="text">
                        <label id="lblcustomer" style="color:red"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date" class="col-md-4 control-label">Date</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                        <input name="date" id="date" placeholder="Date" class="form-control" type="date">
                        <label id="lbldate" style="color:red"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="invoice" class="col-md-4 control-label">Invoice</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input name="invoice" id="invoice" placeholder="Invoice" class="form-control" type="text">
                        <label id="lblinvoice" style="color:red"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group" id="container">
                <label for="product" class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Description</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                        <textarea name="product[]" id="product" class="form-control" placeholder="Product Description"></textarea>
                        <label id="lblproduct" style="color:red"></label>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" id="add" style="text-align:center;">Add More</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->

            <div class="form-group" id="container1">
                <label for="sma_number" class="col-md-4 control-label">SMA Number</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></i></span>
                        <input name="sma_number[]" id="sma_number" placeholder="SMA Number" class="form-control" type="text">
                        <label id="lblsma_number" style="color:red"></label>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" id="add1" style="text-align:center;">Add More</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ebay" class="col-md-4 control-label">eBay Item Number</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></i></span>
                        <input name="ebay" id="ebay" placeholder="eBay Number" class="form-control" type="text">
                        <label id="lblebay" style="color:red"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="shipper" class="col-md-4 control-label">Shipped With</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 selectContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span>
                        <select name="shipper" id="shipper" class="form-control selectpicker">
                            <option value=" ">Please select Shipping Company</option>
                            <option>DHL</option>
                            <option>TNT</option>
                            <option>FEDEX</option>
                            <option>AUSPOST</option>
                            <option>PickUp</option>
                        </select>
                        <label id="lblshipper" style="color:red"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tracking" class="col-md-4 control-label">Tracking Number</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input name="tracking" id="tracking" placeholder="Tracking No" class="form-control" type="text">
                        <label id="lbltracking" style="color:red"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
                <!-- Button -->
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="button" name="save" id="save" value="Save Order" class="btn btn-success">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
    </form>
```

**Ajax script**

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(e){
        //Variables
        var html = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label">Product</label><div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer1" style="padding-left: 20px"><input name="product[]" id="product[]" placeholder="Product" class="form-control" type="text"></div><button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger i_remove_me pull-left" >-</button></div';
        var maxRows = 5;
        var x = 1;

        //Add Rows to the form
        $("#add").click(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x <= maxRows){
            $("#container").append(html);
            x++;
            }
        });

        //Remove rows from the from
        $("#container").on('click','#remove', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        });

    });

        $(document).ready(function(e){
        //Variables
        var html1 = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label">SMA</label><div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer1" style="padding-left: 20px"><input name="sma_number[]" id="sma_number[]" placeholder="SMA Number" class="form-control" type="text"></div><button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger i_remove_me pull-left" >-</button></div';
        var maxRows = 5;
        var x = 1;

        //Add Rows to the form
        $("#add1").click(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x <= maxRows){
            $("#container1").append(html1);
            x++;
            }
        });

        //Remove rows from the from
        $("#container1").on('click','#remove', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        });

    });

</script>
<script>
    //datatable
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#emp_table_details").DataTable();
    });


    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Save Or Insert Data
        $(document).on('click', '#save', function() {
            var customer = $("#customer").val();
            var date = $("#date").val();
            var invoice = $("#invoice").val();
            var product = $("#product").val();
            var sma_number = $("#sma_number").val();
            var ebay = $("#ebay").val();
            var shipper = $("#shipper").val();
            var tracking = $("#tracking").val();
            if (customer == "") {
                $("#lblcustomer").html("Customer Name Required!");
            } else if (date == "") {
                $("#lbldate").html("Date Required!");
            } else if (invoice == "") {
                $("#lblinvoice").html("Invoice Number Required!");
            } else if (product == "") {
                $("#lblproduct").html("Product Required!");
            } else if (sma_number == "") {
                $("#lblsma_number").html("SMA Number Required!");
            } else if (ebay == "") {
                $("#lblebay").html("eBay Number Required!");
            } else if (shipper == "") {
                $("#lblshipper").html("Shipper Required!");
            } else if (tracking == "") {
                $("#lbltracking").html("Tracking Required!");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajaxsave.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        customer: customer,
                        date: date,
                        invoice: invoice,
                        product: product,
                        sma_number: sma_number,
                        ebay: ebay,
                        shipper: shipper,
                        tracking: tracking
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        alert('Your Data Save Sucessful');
                        //document.getElementById('insert_form').reset();
                        //$("#emp_table_details").load('select_data.php');
                        $("#insertModal").modal('hide');
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
</script>
```

**PHP insert to MYSQL code**

```
<?php include 'config/config.php'; ?>
<?php
global $con;
//if (isset($_POST)) {

    $customer = $_POST['customer'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
    $product = $_POST['product'];
    $sma_number = $_POST['sma_number'];
    $ebay = $_POST['ebay'];
    $shipper = $_POST['shipper'];
    $tracking = $_POST['tracking'];;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders(customer, date, invoice, ebay, shipper, tracking)
          VALUES('$customer','$date','$invoice','$ebay','$shipper','$tracking')";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $newOrderId = mysqli_insert_id($con);

    if($query){
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO products(id, product) VALUES('$newOrderId','$product')";
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO sma(id, sma_number) VALUES('$newOrderId','$sma_number')";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

    }
?>
```

Comment: Just looking at the data you send using ajax to your PHP file it's understandable that only the static fields in the form are sent.  When you create new form data elements you have to create unique identifiers for them and then use those unique identifiers to create the data you are sending via ajax. An alternative is when you create new form elements use a unique name everytime and then you can formulate the data you are sending via ajax as follows: ```var form = $("#submissionForm")[0];``` then ```var formData = new FormData(form);```. The send ```formData``` via ajax.

Comment: thanks peter, is it possible you can show me where to put it in the ajax script. also do I have to change anything in the mysql insert statement

Answer (score 0):

Adapt your AJAX call as follows:

```
var form = $("#submissionForm")[0]; //remember to give your form name the id submissionForm
var formData = new FormData(form);              

 $.ajax({
    url: "ajaxsave.php",
    type: "post",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    async: true,
    success: function() {
        alert('Your Data Save Sucessful');
        //document.getElementById('insert_form').reset();
        //$("#emp_table_details").load('select_data.php');
        $("#insertModal").modal('hide');
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

You can then check what values your PHP file receive by writing them to file as follows:

```
<?php
$output = "POSTed variables:\n";    

$customer = $_POST['customer']; $output .= "customer = $customer\n";    
$date = $_POST['date']; $output .= "date = $date\n";
$invoice = $_POST['invoice']; $output .= "invoice = $invoice\n";    

$products = $_POST['product'];  
if (is_array($products))
{ 
  for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($products); $i++)
  {
    $products[$i]; //the value of the array at index i. Save each of these to the database
    $output .= "product[".$i."] = $products[$i]\n";
  }
}    

$sma_number = $_POST['sma_number'];
if (is_array($sma_number))
{ 
  for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($sma_number); $i++)
  {
    $sma_number[$i]; //the value of the array at index i. Save each of these to the database
    $output .= "sma_number[".$i."] = $sma_number[$i]\n";
  }
}

$ebay = $_POST['ebay']; $output .= "ebay = $ebay\n";
$shipper = $_POST['shipper']; $output .= "shipper = $shipper\n";
$tracking = $_POST['tracking']; $output .= "tracking = $tracking\n";

file_put_contents( 'POSTed_vars.txt', $output ); // DEBUG

?>
```

I tested the code by filling out your modal form with multiple products and multiple sma numbers. The text file `POSTed_vars.txt` contained the following, which was exactly what I inserted into the form. It is now just your job to write those values to the database.

```
POSTed variables:
customer = John Doe
date = 2019-10-05
invoice = inv12345
product[0] = Blue Teddy Bear
product[1] = Green Teddy Bear
product[2] = Red Teddy Bear
sma_number[0] = sma12345
sma_number[1] = sma67891
ebay = ebay12345
shipper = DHL
tracking = track12345
```

Hope it helps

Comment: yes but I am having trouble getting the array to ajax, is it possible you can give me an example how to send it to ajax

Comment: @MrPureleb I have edited my answer to answer that question

Comment: @MrPureleb if you want to see the contents of ```formData```, you can loop through it as follows: ```for (var d of formData.entries()) {console.log(d);}```. Maybe do that and report back

Comment: I have changed the script to be $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#save', function() {
            var form = $("#submissionForm")[0];
            var formData = new FormData(form); {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajaxsave.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: formData,
                    success: function() {
                        alert('Your Data Save Sucessful');
                        $("#insertModal").modal('hide');
                        location.reload();

Comment: before I do the foreach loop do I have to change anything above that?

Comment: No, looks good. Remember that you have to also change your PHP.

Comment: Pieter Unfortunately it did not work, the data is not being sent from ajax to php, when I check the the array is empty.

Comment: @MrPureleb I have edited my answer. I have tested it and it works. Please see if you can also get it to work on your side.

Comment: Pieter , sorry about the delay, I will give it a try and report back, thanks for your help